# Select onchange inner function won't run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select (that I have tried standard, as well as MaterializeCSS versions and same results)

```
<select onchange="changeToolBar(this.value)" id="select_toolbar" class="browser-default">
  <option value='0'>Basic</option>
  <option value='1'>Full</option>
  <option value='2'>All</option>
  <option value='3'>Pure</option>
</select>
```

The `changeToolBar Function()`

```
function changeToolBar(expanded) {

  if (expanded === 1) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor.destroy();//destroy the existing editor
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {toolbar: 'Full'});  
    expanded = 2;
    $("#barOutput").text('Pure');
    watchForChanges();
  } else if (expanded === 2) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor.destroy();//destroy the existing editor
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {toolbar: 'Word', removeButtons: 'About'});   // Toolbar 'full' is a default one  
    expanded = 3;
    $("#barOutput").text('Word');
    watchForChanges();
  } else if (expanded === 3) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor.destroy();//destroy the existing editor
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {toolbar: 'Pure'});   // Toolbar 'full' is a default one  
    expanded = 0;
    $("#barOutput").text('Full');
    watchForChanges();
  } else if (expanded === 0) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor.destroy();//destroy the existing editor
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {toolbar: 'Basic'});   // Toolbar 'full' is a default one  
    $("#barOutput").text('Minimalist');
    watchForChanges();
  }
}
```

This function will currently never even be attempted to trigger. It current is not within `$(document.ready()` but I did try it there as well, based on input from another SO article, but it made no difference.

I read that MaterializeCSS breaks `select onchange` so I tried with `browser-default` and got the same results.

I then decided to use standard jQuery `on.change`

```
$('#select_toolbar').on('change', function(){
  changeToolBar(this.value);
  console.log(this.value);
  console.log("Hi");
})
```

This fires - Console logs proper value, and everything. Again, however, that function does not get hit.

While the `changeToolBar` function is weird looks, it actually does work if I tie it to individual buttons that pass `changeToolBar(0)` etc, so I don't believe it's an issue with that.

I must be missing something about how a function within a function is handled.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fe9bx62u/) as an example. It is acting the same way here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of an element is always a string, it's never the number 1, or any number.

You have to either do non-strict comparison

```
if (expanded == 1) {
```

or convert to a number

```
changeToolBar(+this.value)
```

In your fiddle you have an element with the class `barOutput`, and you'd select that with

```
$(".barOutput")
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fe9bx62u/1/)

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for this! I was thinking it would be similar to this and was going to start Googling if that impacted it. Didn't even think to try just comparing with 2 `=` compared to `exact`. Thanks again~ This is perfect.